# Return status code in PHP script then continue

Tags: php, response, flush

Say, I have two servers, server A (shared host, time limits) and B (root server). From server A I'd like to call a time-consuming php script on server B which returns a status code (exit, failure, whatever) but continues to work afterwards. I have fiddled around with http_response_code and flush but with no apparent success. How can this be achieved?

Comment: It sounds very much like you would benefit from using a queue manager (beanstalkd, iron.mq or even redis!)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. What about gearman?

Comment: Gearman could work, though I have no experience with it to offer any real assistance.

Comment: I would accept the comment as the correct answers as it has put me in the right direction. I go and give gearman a try (pecl support and so on)

Answer (score 1):

Use a database table to log your script status on server B. So you can control whether it is already started (you may want to disallow parallel runs), how long is it running and whatever else you like to put to your status message. So you can start your script with one url/script and control it with another.